# Como inserir em um imput um valor de uma combobox (CB) via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um lista clientes em um banco MySQL e estou puxando, via PHP, esses dados para uma combobox e quero que ao usuário ao clicar em um nome do cliente dentro da combobox alguns inputs sejam preenchidos com esse valor, logo depois de clicar em um botão "adicionar". Mas o valor que está sendo retornado é o "id" da CB e não o nome e sobrenome do cliente.

Segue meu form:

```
<form method="post" action="classes/consulta.php">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome_input" class="form-control" name="nome">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Sobrenome</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sobrenome">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Segue meu CB:

```
    <label>Nome do Cliente:</label>
    <select name="ativo" id="nome_CB">
        <?php while($reg = $resposta->fetch_array()) { ?>
        <option  value="<?php echo $reg["cod_cli"]?>"> <?php echo $reg["nome_cli"]." ".$reg["sobrenome_cli"]?> </option>

        <?php }?>
    </select>
    <button onclick="alimentarCampo()" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
```

Segue meu JS:

```
function alimentarCampo() {
var minhaLista = document.getElementById("nome_CB");
document.getElementById("nome_input").value = minhaLista.options[minhaLista.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É que o `value` do option selecionado é o código do cliente. Você precisa pegar o texto da option usando `textContent` em vez de `value`:

```js
function alimentarCampo() {
   var minhaLista = document.getElementById("nome_CB");
   document.getElementById("nome_input").value = minhaLista.options[minhaLista.selectedIndex].textContent;
}
```

```html
<select name="ativo" id="nome_CB">
     <option  value="1">Maria José</option>
     <option  value="2">Fulano Detal</option>
 </select>
 <button onclick="alimentarCampo()" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
 <input type="text" id="nome_input" class="form-control" name="nome">
```

Comment: sera que é possivel separar o nome e o sobrenome, que esta dentro da mesma linha do select, para que cada uma vá para um imput diferente?Ex: "Fulano" em um imput e "Detal" em outro imput.